# How to change empty items within list to N/a values?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with my code. I'm scraping a webppage using BeautifulSoup and I'm looking for all  in a table to get them in a list, but the problem is that when I don't find a image tag I need the value 'N/a' in my list. Now the list element is empty.

This is my code:

```
cards = []

for row in TR_HP1_3[0:11]:
       cards.append([image.get('title') for image in row.find_all('img')])

print(cards)

for x in cards:
     cards_corrected = [x if x != None else "N/a" for x in cards]

print(cards_corrected)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[[], [], [], ['geelrode kaart'], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], ['geelrode kaart'], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

How can I change these empty value to N/a?

Comment: Change it to `[x if x else "N/A"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
cards.append([image.get('title') for image in row.find_all('img')])
```

with:

```
cards.append([image.get('title') if image.get('title') else "N/a" 
              for image in row.find_all('img')])
```